# server client application using java and derby server

Tags: java, derby

i want to make an application for closed network (no internet) that have multiple client accessing central database i am using java and derby server my question is should i make the client access directly the database or i should make a server application that connect the clients to the database? and if so the connection between client and server  will be socket connection and TCP ?  i have searched but all the examples are chat application no data transfer adding data and deleting can any one suggest any examples or tutorials or how to start ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have multiple clients accessing a Derby database simultaneously, you have to employ some sort of server architecture, because only a single embedded Derby application can access a single database at a time.

Derby comes with its own server, however, so you don't have to write your own:

```
[http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/adminguide/cadminov825266.html][1]
```

The connection between Derby network clients and the Derby Network Server is TCP and socket connections, but this will work fine on a closed network so long as the various machines have TCP connectivity to the server.

You can find a Derby tutorial here:

```
[http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can expose the data from the database as a [web data service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_data_services). There are [frameworks that are dedicated](http://www.emergentone.com/) to exposing data to the outside world though [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) / [ROA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource-oriented_architecture). It is a well known pattern. These products usually generate code based on your data and expose them automatically. You can easily write your own too.